# SLURM script fails despite the commands within it working

Tags: slurm, hpc

I am currently trying to run my first SLURM script, but it fails instantly with sbatch as well as srun.
I tested the python commands within it one after the other and they all work on their own, leading me to believe that the culprit lies in one of the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=test_today
#SBATCH -o $HOME/user/%x_%j.txt
#SBATCH -e $HOME/user/%x_%j_error.txt
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
```

Below that there are only the already tested Python-commands, nothing else.

I am thankful for any advice!

Kind regards

Little addendum: neither error- nor output files are created, I am sorry for not mentioning this earlier!

Comment: How it fails? What the error says?

Comment: I do not get an error message,  I only get the status FAILED via e-mail or when checking via scontrol. The output - and error files are not created

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Bash variables in the Slurm directives. In the lines

```
#SBATCH -o $HOME/user/%x_%j.txt
#SBATCH -e $HOME/user/%x_%j_error.txt
```

the `$HOME` variable is not interpreted.

Therefore, the creation of the output and error files fails and Slurm has no file to write any error message. Hence the behavior you observe.

Replace the `$HOME` part with the actual content of that variable and make sure the directory where you want the files to be written exists before submitting the job.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, I fixed this but the SLURM-script still fails without creating the files.

Comment: You are sure about the path? Try first with simply the filename? `--output=`%x_%j.txt` ? It should appear in the directory where you ran the `sbatch` command

Comment: Yes I also tested it with only the filename, still nothing in the directory I run the ```sbatch``` in. I also tried removing several SBATCH commands and only ran it with ```#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --mail-type=END```
but it is still failing

Comment: I found the problem, the slurm script is being executed on another node of the cluster I am working on and this node (for some reason) cannot access my files - it was never a problem of my script. Still thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, my script was executed on another node of the HPC which for some reason cannot access the files necessary to run my script.

Thanks very much to everyone answering and commenting!